# How can I select multiple CSS classes using JavaScript. querySelectorAll is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a nav and header section which both change color (along with the hero text) as the user scrolls down the page, link to fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/mfen723/9swhejo5/35/

I need to select all three of the icon bars that I'm using using for the navbar toggler so they also change color along with the nav,  hero background and text, but I can't seem to select all 3 icon bars.

I am currently using the function below but I understand that using document.querySelector selects only the first matching element

```
  const heroIconBarScroll = document.querySelector('.icon-bar.bar-top', '.icon-bar-bar-middle', '.icon.bar-bottom');

            window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                if (window.scrollY >= 46) {
                    heroIconBarScroll.classList.add('hero-icon-bar-scroll');
                } else if (window.scrollY < 56)
                    heroIconBarScroll.classList.remove('hero-icon-bar-scroll');
            });
```

I have tried using document.querySelectorAll but this seems not to select any of the icon bars.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` takes a single selector. That single selector can use the comma character to combine selectors together.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a single selector string that includes commas, instead of multiple arguments.

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-bar.bar-top, .icon-bar.bar-middle, .icon-bar.bar-bottom');
```

To get all the matching elements rather than only the first, use `document.querySelectorAll` instead of `document.querySelector`.

Then, you will need to loop over the elements of the `NodeList` to manipulate each one.

```js
els.forEach(el => el.classList.add('hero-icon-bar-scroll'));
```

Comment: I think I must have done this wrong as it seems still to be selecting the first element (.icon-bar.top-bar):  'const els = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-bar.bar-top, .icon-bar-bar-middle, .icon.bar-bottom');

            window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                if (window.scrollY >= 46) {
                    els.forEach(el => el.classList.add('hero-icon-bar-scroll'));
                } else if (window.scrollY < 56)
                    els.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('hero-icon-bar-scroll'));
            });

Comment: @MarkFenwick You made a typo in the separate selectors. It should be: `const els = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-bar.bar-top, .icon-bar.bar-middle, .icon-bar.bar-bottom');`

Comment: Typos amended `const els = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-bar.bar-top, .icon-bar.bar-middle, .icon-bar.bar-bottom');` though the class seems still only to be applied to the first element on scroll.

Comment: @MarkFenwick I can't reproduce. Seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/gkcryfs4/

Comment: Found the issue at my side, it works perfectly as per the amended Fiddle.